# Multi column layout with different column heights

Tags: css, css-multicolumn-layout

For a printable layout I want to display a dynamic list (coming from an array) that should 'flow' through 4 columns of different heights, to look like this:

[image]

The blue elements are the four columns with the list (ul) inside.
The heights of the blue columns are fixed.

How can I achieve this with CSS? I looked at multicolumns in css but there the columns have to be the same height so that's not working I guess.

What's the best way to do this? It's fine if it only works in current web browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I checked out 'flexbox' as well as 'css-grid' and even though it may be achievable I resign from doing it. 
Instead I took another way and changed the initial array in the way I can comfortably place it in the different (now not connected) DIVs.